# Create an object with an undetermined data type or change data type

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance

I would like to make a base class class like so:

```
Class baseClass
Protected _Collection() As (this can be multiple types of objects)

Public sub orderCollection()
For i = 0 to _Collection.Length() - 1
_Collection.returnName(i)
Next
```

Now I have two classes that are primarily different but both have returnName() methods. We'll say the collection is vehicles. I can create collections of vans, cars, etc. Is it possible to create inheritance here or is there another way? I looked into various ways, but it seems the _Collection had to have a predetermined data type.

So, I have 4 classes. Van, Car, VanCollection, and CarCollection classes. How could I make it to where the orderCollection method is inherited to both the VanCollection and CarCollection classes or something similar?

Comment: You could use an Interface to do what you say you want, but you could also use Inheritance (perhaps differently than you are).  If Van and Car inherited from Vehicle, it might get you closer to what you are doing.  The collection classes could use `Collection(Of Vehicle)`, but it seems like a Cars collection would want to work with the concrete type.

Comment: Ok, I understand.

I made the array vehicle type, not sure why I didn't understand that the first time I read it. Everything works great. I just call a base class collection and fill it with the child class objects. Learned something new. Thank you!